# Adjusting rspec routing tests for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

When building my app, I generated scaffolds, which created standard Rspec tests. I'd like to use these tests for coverage, but they seem to be failing due to nested routes:

When I run the test, this is its feedback:

```
Failures:

  1) ListItemsController routing routes to #index
     Failure/Error: get("/list_items").should route_to("list_items#index")
       No route matches "/list_items"
     # ./spec/routing/list_items_routing_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.25616 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

How do I tell Rspec that there are nested routes?

Here are the abridged files:

list_items_routing_spec.rb:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ListItemsController do
  describe "routing" do

    it "routes to #index" do
      get("/list_items").should route_to("list_items#index")
    end

end
```

list_items_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe ListItemsController do
  # This should return the minimal set of attributes required to create a valid
  # ListItem. As you add validations to ListItem, be sure to
  # adjust the attributes here as well.
  let(:valid_attributes) { { "list_id" => "1", "project_id" => "1"  } }

  # This should return the minimal set of values that should be in the session
  # in order to pass any filters (e.g. authentication) defined in
  # ListItemsController. Be sure to keep this updated too.
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all list_items as @list_items" do
      list_item = ListItem.create! valid_attributes
      get :index, project_id: 2, {}, valid_session
      assigns(:list_items).should eq([list_item])
    end
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :projects do
    member do
      match "list_items"
    end
  end
```

Notes:
- I've tried changing the rpec tests themselves to include a project_id, and that didn't help.
- I'm using Factory Girl for fixture generation (not sure if this is relevant)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, run `rake routes` to see what routes exist.

According to what you have in your routes I would expect you have a `ProjectsController` that has an action `list_items`. This action would be available under `/projects/:id/list_items`.

Now I can only theorize about what really you want, but I will guess.

If you want `/projects/:project_id/list_items` to route to `list_items#index` you have to change your routes to:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :list_items
end
```

You can confirm that by running `rake routes`.

Then fix the assertion in your routing spec:

```
get("/projects/23/list_items").should route_to("list_items#index", :project_id => "23")
```

**Update for RSpec v2.14+ Expectations**

```
expect(:get => "/projects/23/list_items").to route_to("list_items#index", :project_id => "23")
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I think I necessarily have to have "member do" in my routes file to properly nest and access these files (otherwise I get routing failures). Is there a way to relay this Member relationship to Rspec? Currently when I run the assertion you gave me, it fails with: Failure/Error: get("/projects/23/list_items").should route_to("list_items#index", :project_id => "23")
       The recognized options <{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"list_items", "id"=>"23"}> did not match <{"project_id"=>"23", "controller"=>"list_items", "action"=>"index"}>, difference: <{"project_id"=>"23", "id"=>"23"}>.

Comment: Look. It's your code. Do necessarily what you want. With the member route you the router will route the request to `projects#list_items` which is not what you want I suppose. See Rails Guides on how routing works and how to nest resources: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: I've just noticed that the number representing the id must be in string format.  In my case, @director.id.to_s